# Access the all part of array elements using foreach

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database, foreach

my array is : 
i want to access all part of this array for insert database

```
  'id' => int 1
  'name' => string 'Bitcoin' (length=7)
  'symbol' => string 'BTC' (length=3)
  'website_slug' => string 'bitcoin' (length=7)
  'rank' => int 1
  'circulating_supply' => float 17271050
  'total_supply' => float 17271050
  'max_supply' => float 21000000
  'quotes' => 
    array (size=1)
      'USD' => 
        array (size=6)
          'price' => float 6501.77307056
          'volume_24h' => float 3202089755.7065
          'market_cap' => float 112292447790
          'percent_change_1h' => float 0.14
          'percent_change_24h' => float -0.67
          'percent_change_7d' => float 1.37
  'last_updated' => int 1537115604
```

and my foreach is

```
foreach($filtered as $main)
{
    //print $main['id']."<br>";
    foreach($main as $key=>$value)
    {
        //print $key."  ".$value."<br>";
        if(is_array($value))
        {
            foreach ($value as $key2=>$me)
            {
                //print $key2."  ".$me['price'];
                print $value['id'];
                $Operate=DB::table('coins')->insert(['coin_name' => $value['name'], 'coin_short' => $value['symbol'], 'price' => $value['price'],'last_update'=>$value['last_updated']]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i want to access this elemnt's for insert into database

1. name
2. symbol
3. total_supply
4. price
5. volume_24h
6. market_cap
7. percent_change_7d
8. last_updated

my query Is in the right place ?

Comment: Is the array you show at top the value of `$filtered`?

Comment: You need to loop `foreach ($value['quotes'] as $currency => $quote)`